# Stuck in while True loop python

Tags: python, while-loop

I am stuck in a while True loop which I can't seem to break, any suggestions please:

```
command1 = transporterLink + " -m verify -f " + indir1 + " -u " + username + " -p " + password + " -o " + indir1 + "/VerifyLog.txt -s " + provider1 + " -v eXtreme"
master, slave = pty.openpty()

process = Popen(command1, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=slave, stderr=slave, close_fds=True)
stdout = os.fdopen(master)
while True:
    wx.Yield()
    line = stdout.readline()
    print line.rstrip()
    if not line:
        break
process.wait()
```

Comment: Do you ever get an empty line from `stdout`?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest explanation is that you never get an empty line from `stdout`. Note that `print line.rstrip()` does not modify `line`; for example, if the last line ended with a newline, the loop would continue.

Comment: Thanks NPE, any suggestions on how I could get out of this loop when at the end?

Comment: @speedyrazor You might consider `if not line.strip():` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. I know that at the end of the last line it will return one of two strings so just needed to search for either of these two:

```
process = Popen(command1, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=slave, stderr=slave, close_fds=True)
stdout = os.fdopen(master)
while True:
    wx.Yield()
    line = stdout.readline()
    line = line.rstrip()
    print line
    if "Returning 1" in line:
        break
    if "Returning 0" in line:
        break
```